# Margin and padding in reactstrap?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I'm now starting to move my small project to React. In my project I have used bootstrap4, and I see that in React the more popular approach is to use reactstrap.

I went through the documentation in reactstrap's website and although I see tags such as -xs, -sm, -lg, I don't find the components used for margins and paddings (m-0, r-2 etc).

Inside the docs I saw one place where they acknowledged margin (inside the "Alerts" tab):

```
<p className="mb-0">
      Whenever you need to, be sure to use margin utilities to keep things nice and tidy.
</p>
```

I assume that means that margins and paddings are still used via the bootstrap library. But doesn't it kinda defeats the purpose of reactstrap? Is there a specific reason to not include spacing utilities as components? After all, if I can simply use class names to use bootstrap classes why would I need reactstrap? Why not even use props to set it, like "color"? (not trying to blame the author or anything, just trying to understand the reasoning.)